# Google Cloud Dataprep : Dimensional Modeling

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, dimensional-modeling, google-cloud-dataprep

I'm trying to populate my dimensions and fact tables using **Cloud Dataprep**.

As in a dimensional model, dimensions needs to be populated before populating facts, I have got no success by chaining the flows together using **Reference Datasets** as the successive flows are not getting triggered after completion of first flow and scheduling the flows one after the another becomes risky.

Now, I'm trying to implement this scenario in a single flow i.e., populating dimensions first and then joining them with the factual data to populate data with the dimension key values.

However, in the process the destination for dimensions are populating in a correct manner but the facts destinations are not getting executed.

Can anyone suggest any help?

Comment: I think you can call dataprep template in Composer and you can have all dependencies in there.